# flatten deserialized json using linq into "denormalized" list

Tags: c#, linq

Ultimately this is just a basic .net question, but a little background: I am attempting to use a SQL Server Integration Services script component to pull data from survey monkey's rest API. Because this is happening in a script task in SSIS and registering a helper library in the GAC is not a option, third party libraries are out, as are third party SSIS tools. Obviously this is not the ideal way to go about this, but it's what I'm stuck with for now. I'm able to pull the json data I want with no issues, each one deserialized into an object of type `<SurveyDetail>` and added to a list of that type. Classes:

```
public class SurveyDetail
        {
            public long? Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Nickname { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
            public string Language { get; set; }
            public int? Question_Count { get; set; }
            public DateTime? Date_Created { get; set; }
            public DateTime? Date_Modified { get; set; }  
            public List<Page> Pages { get; set; }             
        }

public class Page
        {
            public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        }

public class Question
        {
            public long? Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public QuestionFamily? Family { get; set; }
            public List<Headings> Headings { get; set; } 
            public QuestionAnswers Answers { get; set; }
        }

public class Headings
        {
            public string Heading { get; set; }
        }

public class QuestionAnswers
        {
            public List<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
        }

public class Choice
        {
            public long? Id { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }      
        }
```

So given a `List<SurveyDetail>`, I want to flatten it into a `List<SurveyQuestionOption>` for ease of staging into the db:

```
public class SurveyQuestionOption
    {
        public long? SurveyID { get; set; }
        public string SurveyTitle { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
        public long? QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
        public string QuestionType { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public long? AnswerOptionID { get; set; }
        public string AnswerOptionText { get; set; }
    }
```

The stumbling block seems to be the fact that the `<QuestionAnswers>` object in `<Question>` can be null sometimes, and my goal is to have nulls in the `<SurveyQuestionOption>` when this is the case, however I am getting null reference exception when trying to do this:

```
List<SurveyQuestionOption> flatData = new List<SurveyQuestionOption>();

    flatData = (from s in surveyDetails
                    from p in s.Pages
                    from q in p.Questions
                    from h in q.Headings.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from c in q.Answers.Choices.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new SurveyQuestionOption
                    {
                        SurveyID = s.Id == null ? null : s.Id,
                        SurveyTitle = s.Title == null ? null : s.Title,
                        DateCreated = s.Date_Created == null ? null : s.Date_Created,
                        DateModified = s.Date_Modified == null ? null : s.Date_Modified,
                        QuestionID = q.Id == null ? null : q.Id,
                        QuestionTitle = q.Title == null ? null : q.Title,
                        QuestionType = q.Family.Value.ToString(),
                        QuestionText = h.Heading.FirstOrDefault().ToString() == null ? null : h.Heading.FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
                        AnswerOptionID = c.Id == null ? null : c.Id,
                        AnswerOptionText = c.Text == null ? null : c.Text
                    }).ToList<SurveyQuestionOption>();
```

I know similar questions have been asked, but I'm still struggling to get the query right for my particular situation. I'm obviously not a .net developer by trade. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by explicit constructors for the null-able members of the `<Question>` type, and supplying a new instance of `<Choice>` for the DeafultIfEmpty like so:

```
public class Question
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public QuestionFamily? Family { get; set; }
    public List<Headings> Headings { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; } 
    public bool? Visible { get; set; }
    public bool? ForcedRanking { get; set; }
    internal string Href { get; set; }
    public QuestionAnswers Answers { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new QuestionAnswers();
    }
}

public class QuestionAnswers
{
    public List<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
    public OtherAnswer Other { get; set; }

    public QuestionAnswers()
    {
        Choices = new List<Choice>();
    }
}



flatData = (from s in surveyDetails
                    from p in s.Pages
                    from q in p.Questions
                    from h in q.Headings.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from c in q.Answers.Choices.DefaultIfEmpty(new Choice())
                    select new SurveyQuestionOption
                    {
                        SurveyID = s.Id == null ? null : s.Id,
                        SurveyTitle = s.Title == null ? null : s.Title,
                        DateCreated = s.Date_Created == null ? null : s.Date_Created,
                        DateModified = s.Date_Modified == null ? null : s.Date_Modified,
                        QuestionID = q.Id == null ? null : q.Id,
                        QuestionTitle = q.Title == null ? null : q.Title,
                        QuestionType = q.Family.Value.ToString(),
                        QuestionText = h.Heading.FirstOrDefault().ToString() == null ? null : h.Heading.FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
                        AnswerOptionID = c.Id == null ? null : c.Id,
                        AnswerOptionText = c.Text == null ? null : c.Text
                    }).ToList<SurveyQuestionOption>();
```